# Android: ImageView and SD-card

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read an image from /mnt/sdcard/img.jpg into ImageView.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/img.jpg");     
imageView1.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

I have write external storage permission.

But ImageView is empty, LogCat don't get any errors,

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think there isn't an image in that path, cause you should know that if the specified filename is null or cannot be decoded into a bitmap the function returns null. So I recommend you to debug and see if your bm instance is != null. :)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, bm == null
But how?
I get an image from Gallerey, path is true

Comment: Just to make sure, log the result of `new File().canRead()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/img.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
imageview1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```